# Bootstrap form-inline

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement a bootstrap form-inline layout on my popup window. My code is just like this one:

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
     <label for="email">Email address:</label>
     <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
     <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
     <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
  </div>
</form>
```

Which looks like this:
[image]

When I resize my popup horizontally The fields switch into a vertical form which is expected. What I really want is to have these textboxes first to go smaller, and then at a certain width if it's been reached drop into a column. Is that even possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend this kind of behavior though its possible. It will cause some issues on small screen devices (UX) whereby a user will see only part of his email and he/she will be unsure whether he/she has entered it correctly.

[Edit] please find below the code:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  .form-inline .form-control {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  .form-inline .form-group {
    display: inline-block;
  }
 }
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/umarmw/h1ezqa01/

[Edit] Field scale down slowly:

https://jsfiddle.net/umarmw/h1ezqa01/1/

Comment: This is a desktop only. However, I understand your concern. You said, it's possible. Can you share how?

Comment: Thanks for the code. Although, I am running your Fiddle and when resizing the screen as soon as Password filed touches the right border it drops into a new row. Shouldn't it get smaller first?

Comment: Just one more question. What if my fields that are in the same inline form should have a different width? Currently you are showing 49% for a form group. If I make email field very narrow then is going to be a large gap between Email and password. Any idea how to adjust it?

Comment: You can add custom class on each field or on the form group and then add new CSS attributes to them.